# Hiding the line of code but not showing end brackets in Visual studio code as flutter writing in Android studio or IntelliJ IDE

Tags: flutter

How can I get the end bracket with comma when I hided the line of code for flutter in Visual studio code?

[image]

Comment: could you please also include your code?

Comment: @eamirho3ein why? op is asking vs code setting